# How to view Teams conversations in chats pane of Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

I want to have all my conversations/chats in one place. Is it possible (maybe even with an app) to view a Teams conversation in the Chats tab of Microsoft Teams? As it is lots of messages get lost because they are separate.

Answer (score 1):

No, currently (as of June 2023) Chats are different from the threaded conversations that happen inside a Team, and you cannot have them in the same panel.

I have heard talk about there possibly being chats added to Teams, distinct from the threaded conversations found in a Team. This is hearsay based on recent MS training though, and should only exist to highlight that chats and threaded conversations are different things and so would not be normally found within the same view in the Teams program.

Comment: Unfortunate answer. I was hoping some 3rd party app could bring them together somehow. I guess I'll just have to wait. Thanks